# Beginner Help - Scraping Ecommerce websites

Tags: scrapy

I am new to scrapy and web crawling. I am trying to scrape data from ecommerce sites in India and am unable to do so.

I am trying to pull the text out of the following hyperlink:

```
<a ng-href="/pd/40011505/figaro-extra-virgin-olive-oil-1-ltr/?nc=cl-prod-list&amp;t_pg=&amp;t_p=&amp;t_s=cl-prod-list&amp;t_pos=1&amp;t_ch=desktop" ng-click="vm.pushToGoogleAnalytics('_trackEvent','item-clicked','custom-page',sectionModel.display_pos+' | '+sectionModel.pageinternalName+' | LNPD | '+sectionModel.internalName+' | '+vm.selectedProduct.sku+' | '+vm.selectedProduct.p_desc +' | '+ vm.itemposition,1)" class="ng-binding" style="text-align: left;" data-original-title="" data-trigger="focus" uib-tooltip="Extra Virgin Olive Oil" data-sectioninteractionplower="{&quot;EventName&quot;:&quot;ItemClicked&quot;, &quot;CustomPageGroup&quot; : &quot;&quot;, &quot;CustomPage&quot;:&quot;&quot;, &quot;ScreenInPageContext&quot; : &quot;cl-prod-list&quot;, &quot;ScreenInPagePosition&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,
            &quot;SectionItemName&quot;:&quot;&quot;, &quot;SectionItemPosition&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}" ng-bind="vm.selectedProduct.p_desc" href="/pd/40011505/figaro-extra-virgin-olive-oil-1-ltr/?nc=cl-prod-list&amp;t_pg=&amp;t_p=&amp;t_s=cl-prod-list&amp;t_pos=1&amp;t_ch=desktop" css="1">Extra Virgin Olive Oil</a>
```

Xpath/Css Selectors are not working for me.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried exactly that didn't work? Could you post your code here?

Comment: Tried -
response.xpath("//div[contains(@qa, 'product_name')]/text()").extract()
response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'ng-binding')]/text()").extract()

Comment: You want to get "Extra Virgin Olive Oil" correct?

Answer (score 0):

To get the text from the a tag I would use the following css selector

```
resp.css('a::text').extract()
```

Response:

```
['Extra Virgin Olive Oil']
```